# What are the possible scaling / resolution options on latest macOS on an external QHD 1440p monitor?

Tags: macos, display, resolution

What are the possible scaling/resolution options on the latest macOS on an external QHD 1440p monitor currently? I know that some people use external apps such as BetterDisplay that unlock resolutions that are not available by default and that works for them, but I'm wondering what currently is provided by default on the latest macOS Sonoma on Macs with M1/M1Pro chips or later on external 1440p monitors. On a 1080p monitor for example I see options listed below:

```
1920 x 1080
1680 x 1050
1600 x 1200
1600 x 900
1344 x 1008
1344 x 756
1280 x 1024
1280 x 960
1280 x 800
1280 x 720
1024 x 768
1024 x 576
960 x 540
800 x 600
1024 x 576 (HiDPI)
960 x 540 (HiDPI)
840 x 525 (HIDPI)
800 x 600 (HiDPI)
```

and I would like to know the options for 1440p monitors. Especially I'm interested in what scaling/resolution options between 2560x1440 and 1920x1080 would be available and if any of them are HiDPI. If anyone has such a monitor and could check that on macOS Sonoma and M1/M1Pro or later it would be great.

Comment: It's possible that the different GPU cores of the Mx, Pro, Max, etc, might offer different ranges. A 1440p display at 24" gives a density of 122ppi, which is nowhere near as high as Apple's Retina display (c. 218), so using scaling is not going to offer much benefit. Everything will be massive, and you'll have less 'real estate'.

Comment: I've yet to be persuaded I need a HiDPI/Retina screen. We have one on one of the newer iMacs & it's fine, but not something I 'need'. I've long considered 1440p on a 27" screen to be just my idea of 'perfect', set at default 2560x1440. Next scales down from that are 2048x1152 & 1920x1080. I've never actually tried either of those, because I just don't need or want everything 'bigger'. There are no HiDPI options, because they're not HiDPI screens.